# How to validate @QueryParam as not null

Tags: groovy, dropwizard

I'm using groovy in a dropwizard project and am trying to return a 404 instead of 500 when a @QueryParam is not specified.

I've tried using the @NotNull flag from javax.validation.constraints.NotNull as well as from com.sun.isstack.NotNull but neither worked properly.

To clarify, I want to return a 404 when the user does not enter a param for one of the specific parameters:

```
  Response getReport(
                              @QueryParam('startDate') String startDate,
                              @QueryParam('endDate') String endDate,
                              @QueryParam('timezone') String zoneId) {
```

Comment: something along the lines of `if !startdate return Response.notFound` is tedious but would work, or as mentioned in http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.1/docs/manual/validation.html use validation and provide an `ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException>` that responds with 404 instead of 400

Answer (score 1):

Try is as an `com.google.common.base.Optional` (dependency is included in Dropwizard):

```
Response getReport(@QueryParam('startDate') Optional<String> startDate,
                   @QueryParam('endDate') Optional<String> endDate,
                   @QueryParam('timezone') Optional<String> zoneId) { ... }
```